# How can I remove the slopes from the curve

Tags: charts, chart.js

So basically the point placement in the chart is correct, the only issue is the shape of the curve since it should follow only the integers values.

What it looks like:

[image]

What it should look like

[image])

Chart code

```
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        
        labels: [{% for value  in x %} '{{value}}',  {% endfor %}],
        datasets: [{ 
            label: '# Des employes',
            data: [{% for c in y %} '{{c}}', {% endfor %} ],
            fill: true,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.5)',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',

            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                ticks:{stepSize:1}
              
            }
            
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `stepped` to `after`

(or `before`, `middle`, `true`):

```js
...
  datasets: [{ 
    stepped: 'after',
      
...
```